# Group by aggregate with some arithmetics (merging similar rows)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, average

I need to combine the following rows:

```
id num_votes avg_vote
1      2      4
1      3      1
1      0      0
```

To end up with this:

```
id num_votes avg_votes
1   2+3+0=5      4*2/5 + 3*1/5 = 2.2
```

I've tried the following, aggregate nested functions don't work of course:

```
select id
     , sum(num_votes) as _num_votes
     , sum(num_votes/sum(num_votes)*avg_vote) as _avg_vote
from mytable
GROUP BY id, num_votes, avg_vote;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
     , sum(num_votes) as _num_votes
     , round(  sum(num_votes * avg_vote)::numeric
             / sum(num_votes)
           , 2) AS avg_votes
FROM   mytable
GROUP  BY id; -- you cannot GROUP BY aggregated columns, just: id
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6e31d/1)

You don't need window functions for this. Aggregate functions do the job.

The calculation:

```
4*2/5 + 3*1/5 + 0*0/5
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
(4*2 + 3*1 + 0*0)/5
```

And implemented as:

```
sum(num_votes * avg_vote) / sum(num_votes)
```

The rest is casting and rounding to preserve fractional digits. (Integer division would truncate.)